# GCM push notifications with out server

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-messaging

I tried GCM-Demo app on both Mobile/AVD and working fine, now as part of my PoC I will get notifications from SAP and using GCM I want to send notifications to Android devices.

I posted message to directly to  ***https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send*** using REST client successfully, please advice me what changes I have to change here to receive on this notification client device...

And I am confused what URL I need to give in CommonUtilities.JAVA , as I sent data directly using REST CLIENT.

static final String SERVER_URL = "`http://host:8080/gcm-demo/`";//is it necessary yo provide server URL ?

```
/**
 * Google API project id registered to use GCM.
 */
static final String SENDER_ID = "1012728190866";
```

In simple words, I will send data using REST instead of SERVER(successfully I sent to GCM),and want to receive notification on device.

Thanks
Rajesh

Comment: I'm not sure the distinction you're making here.  Whatever is going to be making REST requests to GCM is the "server".  Whenever you want to push to a device, you post a REST message to `https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send` with your project identification in headers and the appropriate information and your device should get it.  The device has to have registered with GCM then posted up to you (or you recorded it yourself somehow) it's `registration_id` and that's part of what you send to GCM.

Comment: Hi, I followed blindly the GCM-DEMO with Tomcat to know how it works,and my next step is to avoid TOMCAT and send the messages I receive from SAP...so for this purpose I am trying to send messgaes to GCM from REST Client alone if the messages sent to GCM will GCM send the notifications to connected devices...this is what I want to know.
But I got confused what URL I have to give in CommonUtilites java class..wher I am not hosting on any tomcat server rather I posted directly to GCM using REST .

Comment: what is the purpose of your POC? @RajeshKelam

Comment: I want to send notifications to users(Android/Apple), when an item/product been created/modified/deleted.

Comment: Using SAP NW Gateway I can send the notifications to a listener(any) and form here I wan to send these notifications to users(Android devices).
When I receive notifications I can send directly GCM, and the other sending message from GCM-Device I am looking.....

Comment: Hi All,

I could able to resolve this by my self, once we deploy the client app on device ..we need not to maintain server app on tomcat...if we can send message using simple REST Client to GCM server with Project ID and RegID ...your client app will receive the message sent to GCM by REST.

Below is the link if some one dont want to implement Server side application

http://tausiq.wordpress.com/2013/09/24/android-push-notification-cloud-to-device-messaging/